# Is there a way to associate variables with buttons in Javascript and React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dynamic, state

I am very new to javascript and react, currently and trying to have different buttons (that represent different things) add a "product" to a shopping cart. Each button would contain a product name, and price associated with it and on click it would add that unique name and price to the cart. I am unsure how to associate unique values to a button if this is even possible.

This hard code adds the name "item" and the price "100" to the cart and this is the code associated with it. Where cart and setCart is the state array of all the products in the cart.

```
    const addToCart = async(product) => {
        // Check if duplicates and add to quantity
        //need to somehow pass in the product
        console.log(product);
        let addingProduct = {
        'name': "item",
        'quantity': 1,
        'totalAmount': "100",
      }
      setCart([...cart, addingProduct]);
      console.log(cart);
    };
```

Here is the button code:

```
   <Button id="item" style = {styles.catagory} onClick = {() => addToCart("item")}>
       TEST
   </Button>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to have a "product" which contains a name, quantity, and amount associated with the button or something along those lines? I was imagining something like this:

```
    const addToCart = async(product) => {
        // Check if duplicates and add to quantity
        //need to somehow pass in the product
        console.log(product);
        let addingProduct = {
        'name': product.name,
        'quantity': product.quantity,
        'totalAmount': product.amount,
      }
      setCart([...cart, addingProduct]);
      console.log(cart);
    };
```

Button Code:

```
    <Button product = {"name": <some name>, "quantity": <some quantity>, "totalAmount": <some     amount> style = {styles.catagory} onClick = {() => addToCart(this.product)}>
        TEST
   </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide 'Add to Cart' button to each product element. And when you click on that button, you can always pass the id of the particular product as an argument to the function called with onClick event Handler.

```
<Button onClick={()=>handleClick(id)}>Add To Cart</Button>
```

Like this. Also, define the handleClick function and write your addToCart function there.

Please try and inform me whether it is working or not.

Comment: Thank you, I have a couple questions, first of all is the id presented in your handleClick() function automatically tied to the buttons id?